# Can USB 3.0 be isolated using RF transformers?

Tags: rf, usb, isolation

My project requires an isolated USB connection (without power). Currently we're using a fairly expensive [USB 3.0 isolator](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=igalvanic%20usb%203.0&ia=images&iax=images).

I was wondering if it would actually be possible to achieve smaller and lower cost isolation of the USB data and superspeed lines using little RF transformers, the same way Ethernet achieves isolation. Or, alternatively, capacitors. Presumably, for the superspeed pairs, if the transformers were placed very close to the RX pins at each end of the link, I wouldn't need to re-drive the signals?

Does a component like this exist?

Comment: I have heard that the USB chips use common-Hi/Lo symbols during the negotiation phase. I think these can't be transmitted through an inductively coupled diff. pair. But they could be transferred if you use capacitive separation I guess. Obviously, the latter provides no RF isolation,  but only DC

Comment: There are "cheap" USB 2.0 isolators, perhaps enough?

Comment: @Antonio51 - Unfortunately I really do need the superspeed.

Comment: http://www.advancedphotonics.co.jp/en/usb3-isolator.html (?)

Comment: Assuming the DC signals are being taken care of, 10GBaseT magnetics might do the trick at 5Gbps.

Comment: @tobalt USB 2.0 uses the differential violations for signalling; as far as I know the USB 3.x lanes do not, they are true differential lines. If that's true, the superspeed lanes could be isolated using appropriate RF magnetics, but you'd need to use a different sort of isolator for the USB 2.0 link. (As I understand it, the USB 2.0 link is necessary for initial handshaking, and you can't just use the superspeed lanes and nothing else. That could be wrong though.)

Comment: The USB3 lines are capacitively coupled AFAIK, so definitely no DC signals on the lines for that.  I wonder if you really need to isolate them further (as opposed to the power, ground and USB2 lines)?

Comment: Please link the actual device you use @Rocketmagnet

Comment: @Antonio51 - Thanks. I saw that device already, but it doesn't seem to be available to purchase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, USB3 connectivity does not need USB2 connection, it will work without them just fine. However, USB3 signaling uses two very distinct frequencies to establish the link, first so-called LFPS (as low as 10MHz), up to the main carrier of 2.5 GHz (up to 7-10GHz) to get the optimal signal shape suitable for current USB3 receivers. Therefore it will be difficult to design magnetics to cover the 10MHz-10GHz range. You will be better off to use well-developed fiber-optical solutions to the DC-isolation problem.